# I don't understand the way we get navController inside Activitiy

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I searched a lot and most people used this line of code to get navController in Activity:

```
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
        .findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainerView_mainActivity)
                as NavHostFragment
navController = navHostFragment.navController
```

I am wondering, why we can't just use, `findViewById` method of Activity to get FragmentContainerView.

Answer (score 1):

If the thing you are looking for is `FragmentContainerView` then you can certainly use `findViewById` but if you want to access `NavController` then you have to use the methods exposed by the library.

```kotlin
// from fragments
Fragment.findNavController()
// from views
View.findNavController()
// from activity
Activity.findNavController(viewId: Int)
// from NavHostFragment
navHostFragment.navController
```

Comment: so can we use Activity.findNavController(R.id.fragmentContainerView) to get navController?

Comment: Yeah I haven't tested for FragmentContainerView but I think you should be able to access the navController from the root view as well as any nested views in the view hierarchy